# postgresql cp archive command failed as rsync permission denied

Tags: postgresql, ansible, rsync

I'm trying to set postgresql db setup (version - 10) via ansible and when i was trying to start postgresql db cluster after recovery.conf file i'm getting permission denied error

i'm trying this via anasible and below is the module information

```
- name: Starting the postgresql db cluster on standby host
  command: 'su - postgres -c "pg_ctl -D {{ data_dir }} start"'
  when: inventory_hostname == (groups['pgdb']|sort())[1]
```

## Error message:

```
2021-06-19 13:46:56.129 UTC [90381] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000001 /data/archives/testarchives/000000010000000000000001  && /bin/rsync -a pg_wal/000000010000000000000001 postgres@10.0.1.120:/data/archives/testarchives/000000010000000000000001
2021-06-19 13:46:56.130 UTC [77934] LOG:  archiver process (PID 90381) exited with exit code 1
sh: /bin/rsync: Permission denied
2021-06-19 13:47:56.227 UTC [90385] FATAL:  archive command failed with exit code 126
```

It is clearly stating it is not able to execute rsync command as postgres user.But don't know how to fix this

Tried below first but no luck

```
- name: Starting the postgresql db cluster on standby host
  command: "pg_ctl -D {{ data_dir }} start"
  when: inventory_hostname == (groups['pgdb']|sort())[1]
  become_user: postgres
```

My recovery.conf file is as eblow

```
$ cat recovery.conf
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=postgres host=10.0.1.120 port=5432'
restore_command = 'cp -i /data/archives/testarchives/%f %p'
trigger_file = '/tmp/testtrigger_file'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup -d /data/archives/kongarchives %r 2>>/data/archives/cleanup.log'
```

But if i manually execute the same command then it is working

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-98 ~]$ sudo su - postgres
Last login: Sat Jun 19 15:31:25 UTC 2021 on pts/0
[postgres@ip-10-0-2-98 ~]$ cd /data/dbdata/testdata/
[postgres@ip-10-0-2-98]$ cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000004 /data/archives/testarchives/000000010000000000000004  && /bin/rsync -a pg_wal/000000010000000000000004 postgres@10.0.1.120:/data/archives/testarchives/000000010000000000000004
[postgres@ip-10-0-2-98]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably a victim of SELinux or something like it, in which the same system OS account can have different permissions depending on whether it is running as a daemon or from a command line. Try running below command after this my issue was fixed,

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

refer:https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below.

```
- name: Starting the postgresql db cluster on standby host
  command: 'sudo -u postgres psql -c "pg_ctl -D {{ data_dir }} start"'
  when: inventory_hostname == (groups['pgdb']|sort())[1]
```